# How to sort documents by custom (non-natural ordered) field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

I'm experimenting with MongoDB and its aggregation framework. With unwind operation I can split a document with an array field to multiple documents for each array index. Now if the array has data which has no natural sorting order, how can I sort this in MongoDB?

Example:

A products collection has the following documents (_id field omitted)

```
{ "type" : "t-shirt", "size" : [ "S", "M", "L" ] }
{ "type" : "pants", "size" : [ "XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL" ] }
```

After unwinding the collection data by `size` field, the results are

```
{ "type" : "t-shirt", "size" : "S" }
{ "type" : "t-shirt", "size" : "M" }
{ "type" : "t-shirt", "size" : "L" }
{ "type" : "pants", "size" : "XS" }
{ "type" : "pants", "size" : "S" }
{ "type" : "pants", "size" : "M" }
{ "type" : "pants", "size" : "L" }
{ "type" : "pants", "size" : "XL" }
```

The size field has no natural ordering, XL and XS for example are sorted next to each other, although they should be sorted to first/last position.

I *migth* get this solved by first projecting the each size to its corresponding number, i.e. XS=1, S=2... But **is there any easier way to perform custom sorts?**

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is no easier way but you have three ways to do it,

1) as you specified you can use 
`$project` and put put number 123 according to size and sort it on that numbers

2)you can sort on second character of the size string asc by substr 2 character and sorting it

3)use `$text` to sort on depending on its weight

Comment: Only if `$substr` could perform splitting starting from end, then I could get the last digit, which indicates the actual size. This doesn't completely solve the problem though, since then 'XS' and 'S' would be treated the same.

Comment: Can you explain a bit, how `$text` could be used in this context?